# What is a common workflow for local development for shopify themeing?

Tags: localhost, shopify

I've downloaded my shopify theme locally and have themekit installed. I've tried the `theme open` command with `env=development`. And that opened my live site.

I get that I can potentially edit files more easily locally. But is there any workflow around seeing these changes with like a localhost? Or must I essentially sync the local changes with my production site to see them?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, with more searching I found `theme watch` which pushes changes to local files back up to the production site. This is not quite a typical local development workflow. But as long as you are essentially working on a private app emulates the process.

Comment: Shopify is probably releasing a new tool this year, one specific to allow theme development locally, without the current hassles of having to use the Internet to push changes. Early Shopify had an App to provide this, so I am assuming that project was resurrected.